# Jquery .load "cannot get"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using .load to switch content in my #content div but when I click on a link it brings me to a white page saying "cannot get /index" or whatever. 
The initial content does get loaded so I know the first three lines of code work.
Any ideas why I "cannot get" my other files?

Here's my HTML

```
<div id="nav">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // initial
    $('#content').load('content/index.html');

    // handle menu clicks
    $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.html');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: is it `Portfolio.html` or `portfolio.html` ?

Comment: Check if the requested URL is correct. You can do this using Firebug or similar dev tools. Press `F12` on a browser to bring up the dev tools.

Comment: its lower case @MohammadAdil , I checked.
Well I'm pretty sure it is, as the index.html resides along with portfolio and about

Comment: You have `Portfolio` `-->` Uppercase `P` in your href. that will try to load `Portfolio.html`

Comment: sorry, I changed it after I put it on here. I'll edit that now

Comment: Do you see any error on console ?

Comment: Can you post the full `ul` ? I am suspecting that your html does not quite correspond to the jquery selector used. You are using `$('ul#nav li a')` but your `a` are residing in the same level and they are not nested inside `li` Therefore the `click` event is not even bind at all

Comment: "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature." That's from the console when I click on a link

Comment: its in the edits @Mahmud

Comment: Posted the answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // initial
$('#content').load('content/index.html');

// handle menu clicks
$('div#nav ul li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.html');
    return false;
});
});
```

Shortly, the `#nav` is the id of the `div` not the `ul` so `$('ul#nav li a').` should have been `$('div#nav ul li a').` more precisely `$('div#nav > ul > li > a').`

If you want animations like fade, try this -

```
$('div#nav ul li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.html', function(){
            $('#content').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

But for sliding animation its gonna be a little tricky, cause you have to do something like that -

1. Fist slide left by animating width
2. Then take the div to the right end of the window using css `left`
3. Load it and make the width normal
4. change the `left` to make it slide left again.

This will give you a space between animations, but if you want spaceless animation, then you will have to use more divs and a little more logics. Happy experimenting.. :)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thanks you so much!

Comment: A little off-topic...But How would I then make the transitions between pages smoother? like fly in the from the left? or fade in ?

Comment: Updated my answer with fade, but slide is a little complex, so just described one of the ways to make a slide, left it for yourself to try out.. :)

Answer (score 0):

*As per your edit*

You have a wrong jQuery selector, it should be -

```
$('#nav ul li a').click...
```

Comment: the `return false;` from the code should take care of that problem

Answer (score 0):

When the **content is loaded dynamically** the **actions on html elements will not be catched by direct .click()** function So:

Use `$(document).on('click', 'ul#nav li a', function() {`

Instead of `$('ul#nav li a').click(function() {`

This Worked for me